# macros and IF statements

Tags: excel, vba

i have 2 qns, hopefully simple enough for you to help me with.
1) i have 2 adjacent cells A and B. A is a validated list where it has 2 values. B should show something else that is dependent on A. my intention is to set this macro on a button and everytime the button is clicked, the 2 cells appear. 
2) i have 4 cells- C, D, E. cells C, D, E are validated drop downs. when a value in C is selected, only the corresponding values appear in D, and E is dependent on the selection of C and D. 
i am very new to macro and aint very sure with excel scripting. hopefully i can get help from you.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to follow. Let me ask a little bit about #1:

Do you want

x) To press a button, have inputs for A and B appear, choose a value for A and see the result of B, and press Accept or something?

or

y) Choose a value for A by validation drop-down box, then see the value for B and do something with it automatically?

or

z) something else?

(If we can clarify this, the question part #2 might make more sense. Thanks!)

Comment: almost (y) i guess.
suppose cell A is at A2 and B is A3
i have set "=IF(A2="one","something","") at cell A3, knowing that choosing "one" will return "something" at cell A3 and blank when i choose something else.
i wish to record this simple formula as a macro and play it using a button because i may use this crap many times in the same spreadsheet. however i know that the value of cell A2 changes everytime i play it on a different cell. 
my qns is how do i go about replacing the new value of A2 everytime i play the macro?